# jquery detect change in dom outsite jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible using jQuery (or any other JavaScript function) to detect when an onmouseover event is fired?

I have a page where existing javaScript calls a onmouseover/out events to re-write the contents of the div. I'm actually only interested in getting at what the div contains while the mouse is hovered over it.  The onmouseover event is generated server-side by a program I don't have the ability to change :(.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an even more specific example:

```
$("#idOfYourControl").hover(
   function() { $('#divToShowText').text($(this).text()) }, 
   function() { $('#divToShowText').text("") }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#idOfYourControl").hover(function() { /*mouseover event*/ }, function() { /*mouseout event*/ });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mouseover event handler in jQuery.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover#fn

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the server is writing the original mouseover handler out, you can use a simple overwrite to add your own hook that you can then use to detect the old one being fired:

```
var oldHandler = yourElement.onmouseover;
yourElement.onmouseover = function() {
    //Do whatever new code you want here...
    $j.trigger('oldHandlerCalled');

    oldhandler();
}
```

Kind of a quick and dirty example, but you get the idea. No guarantees that this won't leak memory in IE6 ;)

If the server is attaching the event via jQuery, you can look in yourElement.data.events and do it in a much tidier way than this.